# How to SUM column while using a condition on each cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Google Sheets and i have a table with 2 columns: PRICE(A) and REQUIRED(B):

```
--------------------
| PRICE | REQUIRED |
--------------------
| 10000 | *        |
|  1200 | *        |
|  1550 |          |
|  5000 |          |
| 12000 | *        |
--------------------
```

I need to calculate the SUM of the column A (PRICE) but only if REQUIRED is set (has a star)
so basically i need to go through the PRICE column, and check each cell to see if the REQUIRED cell is set for it.

How can i accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[`sumif()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583) would suffice*

```js
=sumif(<Required_column>, "*", <Price_column>)
```

***example***: `=sumif(B:B,"*",A:A)`

Comment: Perfect, it worked, thank you very much!